# How to clear saved states when navigation in jetpack compose when pressing bottom bar tab?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a navigation bottom bar in jetpack compose with 3 tabs (Home, Tasks, Options)
and the Home tab contain two screens
Home -> FirstScreen -> SecondScreen (with passing data)

```
sealed class BottomBarScreen(
    val route: String,
    val label: String,
    val icon: ImageVector
) {
    object Home: BottomBarScreen(
        route="home",
        label="Home",
        icon= Icons.Rounded.Home
    )
    object Tasks: BottomBarScreen(
        route="tasks",
        label="Tasks",
        icon= Icons.Rounded.CheckCircle
    )
    object Options: BottomBarScreen(
        route="options",
        label="Options",
        icon= Icons.Rounded.Settings
    )
}
```

and this is the graph

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    paddingModifier: Modifier
) {
    NavHost(navController = navController,
        startDestination = BottomBarScreen.Home.route
    ) {
        composable(route= BottomBarScreen.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen(paddingModifier, navController)
        }
        composable(route = HomeViews.FirstScreen.route) { FirstScreen(navController) }
        composable(route = HomeViews.SecondScreen.route + "/{id1}" + "/{id2}") {
            val data1 = it.arguments?.getString("id1")!!
            val data2 = it.arguments?.getString("id2")!!
            SecondScreen(navController, data1, data2)
        }
        composable(route= BottomBarScreen.Tasks.route) {
            TasksScreen(paddingModifier)
        }
        composable(route= BottomBarScreen.Options.route) {
            OptionsScreen(paddingModifier)
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the bottom bar

```
@Composable
fun AppBottomBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    val screens = listOf(
        BottomBarScreen.Home,
        BottomBarScreen.Tasks,
        BottomBarScreen.Options
    )
    BottomNavigation() {
        screens.forEach { screen ->
            AddItem(
                screen = screen,
                navController = navController
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowScope.AddItem(
    screen: BottomBarScreen,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val backStackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    BottomNavigationItem(
        label = {
            Text(text = screen.label)
        },
        icon = {
            Icon(
                imageVector = screen.icon,
                contentDescription = screen.route + " icon"
            )
        },
        selected = screen.route == backStackEntry.value?.destination?.route,
        onClick = {

                navController.navigate(screen.route) {


                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                        saveState = true
                    }

                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true

                }



        }
    )
}
```

**WHAT I WANT:** when i'm in firstscreen or secondscreen and i press home tab again i want it to go back to the start destination of the home (the main home screen) it

**THIS ONLY WORKS:** this works fine when i delete the saveState and restoreState from the code

**THE PROBLEM:** i want a solution to clear the saved state when i press home tab again

Note: when using the code with ( saveState and restoreState) i can navigate between tabs and when i go to firstscreen and then to another tab and go back to home its saves the state but i cant clear it when i press home tab again

Comment: What if you use ```popBackStack()``` instead of ```popUpTo```